# React.js - changing text in a list

Tags: reactjs

I am changing the text colour in a list when the item is clicked. Ideally, I would like to have a toggle function so only 1 item is highlighted at a time. The following code works however I can't stop thinking there is a much better way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const listItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "About",
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Contact",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Products",
    selected: false,
  },
];

const ListView = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(listItems);

  const handleListClick = (id) => {
    setMenuItems([...menuItems.map((item)=> {
      if (item.id === id){
        item.selected=!item.selected
      }
      return item
      })])
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {listItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              onClick={() => handleListClick(item.id)}
              style={item.selected ? { color: "red" } : { color: "Blue" }}
            >
              {item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListView;
```

Any ideas on simplifying this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array index to update the item only without traversing the array like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const listItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "About",
    selected: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Contact",
    selected: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Products",
    selected: false,
  },
];

const ListView = () => {
  const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState(listItems);

  const handleListClick = (index) => {
    const items = [...menuItems];
    items[index].selected = !items[index].selected;

    setMenuItems(items);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {listItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              onClick={() => handleListClick(index)}
              style={item.selected ? { color: "red" } : { color: "Blue" }}
            >
              {item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListView;
```